# Does the Mandelbrot fractal contain countably or uncountably many copies of itself?

Tags: infinity, fractals

I've been working on a program that draws fractal images, and I was struck by a question that came to mind.

It is clear that the Mandelbrot fractal contains infinitely many copies of itself, but I've been wondering, is it a countable or uncountable infinity?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is similar to the mathstack question, [mandelbrot-bulbs-countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244264/mandelbrot-bulbs-countable).  It turns out that every bulb/Cardioid has a hyperbolic center that is the solution of an algebraic equation; and algebraic numbers are countable.  The hyperbolic centers are all zeros of the following sequence of equations: $f_1=x$, $f_2=x^2+x$, 
$$f_{n}=(f_{n-1})^2+x$$ 
$$f_{n}=0$$

The roots of each of the $f_n$ equations are the hyperbolic centers.  The main Cardioid of every mini-mandelbrot also has a main hyperbolic center, which represent a subset of these countable algebraic numbers.

For example, consider the roots of $f_4=0$.  Two of these zeros are $x=-0.156520166833755\pm1.03224710892283i$, which are the hyperbolic center of the largest period 4 mini-mandelbrot, and its conjugate
$f_4 = x^8 + 4x^7 + 6x^6 + 6x^5 + 5x^4 + 2x^3 + x^2 + x$.  Another zero is -1.94079980652948 which is a smaller period 4 mini-mandelbrot.  The other zeros are period=4 and period=2 bulbs, as well as the period=1 main Cardioid at x=0.

Another example is $f_3=x^4 + 2x^3 + x^2 + x$.  One of the zeros of $f_3=0$ is $-1.75487766624669$, which is the hyperbolic center of the main Cardioid of the largest period 3 mini-mandelbrot.

Comment: Can you point me to where I can learn about *why* the Mandelbrot fractal has this property that the hyperbolic centers are zeroes to a series of equations?  Is the converse true, that every solution to every equation in the series is the center of a bulb or cardioid?

Comment: Converse is true.  see: Complex Dynamics by Lennart Carleson, Chapter 8.1, Quadratic polynomials, the Mandelbrot set.  Super attracting points have derivative of zero.  These are centers of repeating components, $f^n=f^0$, where the derivative is zero.  Turns out all bulbs/cardioids have such a center point where the derivative is zero, which means that center is asolution of f^n(0)=0.

Comment: Also, see this mathstack question; http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/491279/mandelbrot-boundary/499238#499238   Each Period n component has a period "n" attracting fixed point.  If the fixed point is zero (at the center), it is super-attracting.  The boundary of the component is where the fixed point changes from attracting to neutral, or parabolic.

Answer (score 12):

Every copy has a central cardioid with finite, positive area, disjoint from all the other copies' central cardioids. The areas must add up to a finite number; thus, there can't be uncountably many of them, as a sum of uncountably many positive numbers can't be finite.

Answer (score 3):

As @Sheldon suggested, I looked at the "Mandelbulb" countable question, and the answer given there is awesome, some I'm adding it here as "Community WIKI".

I like the way the answers above provide so much new information, but I love the simplicity of this explanation.

> I don't know if you have a precise definition of "bulb", but it's
>   reasonable to expect that any bulb ought to contain a sufficiently
>   small ball. Any ball contains a point with rational coordinates,
>   because the latter are dense. Assuming bulbs are disjoint, this lets
>   us define an injection from bulbs to rational points, which are
>   countable, therefore there cannot be uncountably many bulbs.