# How many smaller Mandelbrot sets are inside the Mandelbrot set?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, math-history, fractals

When zooming in on the Mandelbrot set you will very often find replicas of the original zoomed out image. Is it possible to find out how many the entire set includes?

Comment: [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Mandelbrot_sequence_new.gif) link should help you visualise. You'll get your answer in an instant.

Comment: They are actually not exact copies, but there are infinitely many.

Comment: It wouldn't be the Mandelbrot set if you didn't find infinite copies within every copy.

Comment: further to the other comments, there are only countably infinitely many, because each has a positive area, they do not overlap, and the whole set is contained in a disc of radius 2

Comment: Even furthering the comments of @Claude, the answers at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/743727/does-the-mandelbrot-fractal-contain-countably-or-uncountably-many-copies-of-itse establish that there are a (countable) infinity of "replicas" within the set. It's a good first question, and don't get discouraged. Welcome to site!