# Is there a Julia fractal that contains uncountable many copies of itself?

Tags: set-theory, dynamical-systems, infinity, fixed-point-theorems, fractals

We know that the Mandelbrot fractal contains a countable number of copies of itself.

See :

[Does the Mandelbrot fractal contain countably or uncountably many copies of itself?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/743727/does-the-mandelbrot-fractal-contain-countably-or-uncountably-many-copies-of-itse)

Where that is explained.

Notice that polynomials have a finite amount of zero's and entire functions have a countable amount of zero's.

So I started to wonder :

Is there a Julia fractal that contains uncountable many copies of itself ?

And if so, can they be iterations of entire functions ?

What are typical examples ?

Comment: Think about how e.g. you can't pack uncountably many disjoint "X-shapes" (for pretty much any interpretation of that phrase) in the plane. The same basic argument will apply to any set that's much more complicated than a line segment.

Comment: @NoahSchweber If the size shape has a positive area on a surface or a positive volume in a space, you are probably correct.... But what if it does not ? Like some kind of sponge or so ?

Comment: If packing the shapes obligates that the "holes" between them have positive area (which I believe is the case NoahScheweber is asking you to consider) then from your comment I think you already agree with him, no?

Comment: @RonKaminsky well it makes alot of sense. But I would not call it a proof yet ?

Comment: I was thinking double exponential shrinking of copies and vitali sets and other monsters maybe ....

Comment: The Julia set of $z \to z^2 - 2$ is a line segment, which contains uncountably many line segments; however only countably-many are related to the dynamics, so this is more of a coincidence than anything structural.  (Thanks for @NoahSchweber's hint.)

Comment: What prevents something like a Smith–Volterra–Cantor set type structure or more complicated that implies uncountable ?